# Where to report QGIS and QGIS-Plugin bugs?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I often find bugs in QGIS and its Plugins.

I would like to ask about this on the internet but I do not seem to find the proper place to address this issue.

Are there any instructions?

Comment: Proper link is http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Bugs and  http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For QGIS, see https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues

For plugins, see http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ and select the plugin, then go to the `Details` tab.

You need an OSGeo account to fill tickets. After creating that, go to your OSGeo user page. Then you can login to hub.qgis.org with the same user ID.

Comment: are there special restrictions for the OSGeo Userid, thee say "This userid should be usable with the main OSGeo web site, and various other OSGeo services, including OSGeo hosted project subversion and Trac. OSGeo userids are stored in a central LDAP server". no idea what that means ...

Comment: It means that the same account is used for the OSGEO web site, QGIS, SVN and trac. The only restriction is that it has to be different from the Userid's already created.

Answer (score 4):

Many QGIS Plugins uses GitHub as their primary issue tracker. Issue tracker is usually specified in the plugin's metadata `<home>/.qgis2/python/plugins/<plugin>/metadata.txt`.

For plugins that use GitHub issue tracker, one can use [Report](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/report/) plugin to [facilitate reporting](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2016/05/12/qgis-report-plugin/) of the bugs/enhancements.