# QGIS server pie chart false rendering

Tags: qgis, qgis-server

I am currently working with QGIS 2.4 on Windows 8.1 pro and with QGIS-server on Debian 7. I want to publish a map with diagram but the render is not good.[image: The renders on the desktop version (right) and by server version (left)]
At right is the desktop map and at left the server version. The circular diagram stays black on the server version.

Is anyone already uses and success to display diagrams and histograms with qgis-server ?

Comment: It might be worth to report this as a bug, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50769/where-to-report-qgis-and-qgis-plugin-bugs