# How to simply report wrong language translation in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, internationalization

I noticed that the "Eliminate sliver polygons" option in QGIS 2.4. has wrong translation in Croatian language (translated as silver), so I decided to report it.

In official page there are instructions how to become translator: http://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/translate.html#translators-mailing-list
Registration is required for access to mailinglist, so I did it. After registration, there was next message: "Your subscription request has been received, and will soon be acted upon. Depending on the configuration of this mailing list, your subscription request may have to be first confirmed by you via email, or approved by the list moderator. If confirmation is required, you will soon get a confirmation email which contains further instructions."

Few days have passed, and there is nothing in my mailbox.
So, the question is: How to SIMPLY report a wrong language translation in QGIS?
I hope that the Croatian translator will see this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:

Werner Macho just posted the following information on the mailing list:

> Regarding translation it is now easier than ever before to contribute
>   and change the things yourself. Just get an account on transifex https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/QGIS
>   and apply for the italian language - search for the typos and change
>   them by yourself. That way you make sure the correct string will find
>   it's way into the next release.

---

Original:

Try sending an email to the translators mailing list from the email account you registered. Most likely it works even though you might not have received a confirmation mail for whatever reason.

An alternative is to create a bug report. There is a category for Translations there. See also [Where to report QGIS and QGIS-Plugin bugs?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50769/where-to-report-qgis-and-qgis-plugin-bugs).

Comment: This kind of information is really valuable - bug reporting is a bit opaque for most people!

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to send a message to Croatian translator, which means that my duty is accomplished. We'll see if there's going to be any reaction.

Answer (score 1):

Since the QGIS team was very busy with launching QGIS 2.6 over the last days, your subscription may have come at the wrong time.

Try to subscribe again, or contact Werner Macho directly. You will find his address at http://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/governance/organisation/governance.html#gui-translation

Apart from that, you might have to sign in to transifex, as Anita explained.