# How do I file a QGIS bug report through alternative means?

Tags: qgis, gps

I have tried to file a bug report per the instructions on the QGIS get involved page.
Signed up for an osgeo account, but keep on getting kicked off.

It could be my connection (Wireless DSL, wildly varying speeds, and connection reliability)

The bug refers to Version 2.14.---  GPS Information module which does not record a point.  There are two other questions/reports concerning this here starting on May 28th.

Can someone else report this, or provide a solution so I can file the report myself?

Comment: Thank you.
I will do as you suggest, but you have more than one user, on multiple systems reporting this issue here. I have not seen a report for this issue in places where we are suggested to look.

Comment: Have you visited your OSGEO user page? I remember I could not log in  to hub.qgis,org unless I visited that page.

Comment: See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50769/where-to-report-qgis-and-qgis-plugin-bugs for the usual way of login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the bug tracker doesn't work for you, consider writing to the [QGIS user mailing list](https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-user).

It usually doesn't make much sense for other users to report bugs that they don't encounter or cannot reproduce themselves because they cannot answer potential follow-up questions.

Comment: @jbgramm I noticed that you sent to the UX (usability) instead of the user list. Questions about working with QGIS and tracking down potential bugs should happen on the user mailing list https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-user

Comment: I will add my bug report there as well.